# PhotoImage gif wont appear

Tags: python, tkinter

I am getting json data from openweathermap and i want to use the image corresponding to the current weather. I have downloaded all the images and have a list with their names. Then depending on the data i get i use a function to confirm that the image does indeed exist in my directory, and then i load it to be used in the main program.

```
wimg = PhotoImage(file='01d.gif')
exists = False    
if data["weather"][0]["icon"] in imagelist:
        wimg = PhotoImage(file=data["weather"][0]["icon"]+'.gif')
        exists = True    
        print  data["weather"][0]["icon"]   

return weatherdata, exists, wimg
```

Then another function takes over which displays the weather and handles the image.

```
def clicked():
    userinput = entrytext.get()
    a, exists, wimg=projectlibrary.basicMechanism1(userinput)
    weathertext.set(a)
    labeltext.set(userinput)
    if exists:
        iconlabel.config(image=wimg)
        iconlabel.grid(row=5,column=0)
```

The shape of the image shows on the label but the image itself does not. What i get is a blank (white) 50x50 box on my label. What can i do to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to fix the indentation in your code.

Comment: @BryanOakley Fixed. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: What is `projectlibrary.basicMechanism1()` ?

Comment: I think your first code block has some missing line like `def ...`

Comment: probably http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm

Comment: @IronFist  the first code piece is part of a function called basicMechanism1. I didn't include the entire function cause the rest doesn't have to do with the images. It's merely for displaying the weather data

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  Following that, you would create and post complete code with extraneous stuff removed.  We should not have to guess that the first posted block is extracted from a particular place.